# Vertically centering element to it's siblings height

Tags: css, flexbox, positioning, centering

I'm trying to center vertically `.container img:nth-child(2)` to its siblings height but it just doesn't work. I tried to center it vertically with a lot of commands (and adding it to both - .container and .child) but nothing happened. 
[image]
Also, when the window is scaled down, I want the first `.container img` child to be centered and above the second one. The whole container should also be horizontally aligned to the center of browser windows width (screenshot attached).[image]

Is it possible without using media queries? Could you guys help me out? I'm a beginner and I'm really trying to figure those displays and positioning out...

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.parent {
  background-image:url("http://bossfight.co/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/boss-fight-free-high-quality-stock-images-photos-photography-trees-forest-mist.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
}
.parent h1 {
  margin-top:0;
  padding-top: 2em;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: helvetica;
}
.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 2em;
  width: 100%;
}

.child {
  display: inline-flex;
  padding: 0 5px;
}

.container img {
  float: left;
}

.container a {
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.container a:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>random title</title>
  
  
  
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

  
</head>

<body>
  <div class="parent">
  <h1>Heading example</h1>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="child">
      <a href="_top">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/90x90" alt="ux-button">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/150x40" alt="ux-button">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="child">
      <a href="_top">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/90x90" alt="ux-button">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/150x40" alt="ux-button">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="child">
      <a href="_top">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/90x90" alt="ux-button">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/150x40" alt="ux-button">
      </a>
    </div>
</div>
  
  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is there a reason you are trying to avoid media queries?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use nested flexbox with media queries.

Make each anchor link as flexbox.

```
.container a {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

Switch `flex-direction` value in the media queries.

```
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .container a {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.parent {
  background-image: url("http://bossfight.co/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/boss-fight-free-high-quality-stock-images-photos-photography-trees-forest-mist.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
}
.parent h1 {
  margin-top: 0;
  padding-top: 2em;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: helvetica;
}
.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  /* align-content: center; */
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 2em;
  width: 100%;
}
.child {
  padding: 0 5px;
}
.container img {
  /* float: left; */
}
.container a {
  opacity: 0.5;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.container a:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .container a {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <h1>Heading example</h1>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="child">
      <a href="_top">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/90x90" alt="ux-button">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/150x40" alt="ux-button">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="child">
      <a href="_top">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/90x90" alt="ux-button">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/150x40" alt="ux-button">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="child">
      <a href="_top">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/90x90" alt="ux-button">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/150x40" alt="ux-button">
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make your  have display:flex; justify-content:center; flex-direction:row
and have the  be flex: 0 1 auto; align-self: center;

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.parent {
  background-image:url("http://bossfight.co/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/boss-fight-free-high-quality-stock-images-photos-photography-trees-forest-mist.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
}
.parent h1 {
  margin-top:0;
  padding-top: 2em;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: helvetica;
}
.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 2em;
  width: 100%;
}

.child {
  display: inline-flex;
  padding: 0 5px;
}

.child>a{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content:center;
}

.child>a>img{
  flex:0 1 auto;
  align-self:center
}

.container img {
  float: left;
}

.container a {
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>random title</title>
  
  
  
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

  
</head>

<body>
  <div class="parent">
  <h1>Heading example</h1>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="child">
      <a href="_top">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/90x90" alt="ux-button">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/150x40" alt="ux-button">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="child">
      <a href="_top">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/90x90" alt="ux-button">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/150x40" alt="ux-button">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="child">
      <a href="_top">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/90x90" alt="ux-button">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/150x40" alt="ux-button">
      </a>
    </div>
</div>
  
  
</body>
</html>
```